# mongodump references wrong db directory

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I had an install of MongoDB that was using on OSX that was using `~/data/db`.  I had a crash and re-installed MongoDB using Homebrew and it set up the new db path at `~/usr/local/var/mongodb`.

All of my apps are working (default port 27017), but when I try to run `mongodump` it backs up the db in `~/data/db` which is now out of date.

How can I get `mongodump` to reference the correct db folder?

Comment: What version of mongodump are you using and how exactly are you calling it? By simply executing `mongodump` in the terminal?

Comment: The version is `3.6.5`.  And yep, calling it from terminal.  (I'm also using it in a bash script but it performs the same way for both.)

Comment: Since version 3.2 (IIRC) mongodump does not accept `--dbpath` argument. It now requires a live server. So chances are good that either a) you're mistaken about which data dir your server uses or b) there are _two_ servers on the machine and mongodump is talking to a wrong one.

Comment: I'm confident about the correct data dir.  Timestamps show which one is getting updated.  Not sure about two servers running though...  how could I check that?

Comment: Try something like `ps aux | grep mongod`. Followup question: How do you know that mongodump dumps the wrong data dir?

Comment: Looks like there might be two running:   
367   0.0  0.2  5226396  27108   ??  S    14Feb19   6:03.43 /usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

72163   0.0  0.0  4277252    824 s010  S+    9:48AM   0:00.00 grep mongod

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189079/discussion-between-brian-flanagan-and-sergio-tulentsev).